# Gathering data for machine learning (finance data)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, finance, stock

So larger macro question here; I'm working on a machine learning model to predict long term performance of stocks using NLP of financial reports and different data from each yearly financial report. So the thing that I am wondering is what to do about different sized data.

So for example I can only get data 27 years back for one company but 100 years back for another. So I guess my question is how can I set it up so that it trains on each company as a single instance? When the ideal epoch size is not going to be constant as the amount of data per company is going to vary?

So the one thing I thought of is to standardize it, and give every company say 300 years of data, and autofill the data that doesn't exist with a impossible value that the model can learn represents no data, so that way if I set the epoch size to 300 it will see one/use a sliding window on one company.

So just wondering if this is a good solution or if there are better solutions out there. Thanks!

Comment: There are thousands of things that impact stock prices adversely and they are completely random in their nature, so "efficient market hypothesis" is a wrong assumption and Technical Analysis is a not a scientific method - you can't predict the stock price the way you predict Fibonacci sequence. If yesterday the was a sunrise, a day before there was a sunrise, does that mean tomorrow there will be sunrise? *No, it doesn't* - a huge unexpected or unprecedented event can cause both Sun and Solar system to stop existing all together, so there will be no sun to rise. Entropy is always there.

Comment: I mean sure but if we talk in terms of probability there is an extremely high probability that the sun will come up tomorrow, so I don't really understand your point at all. Would this model predict covid? absolutely not; but can it look at the overall performance and valuation of a company and come away with a pretty good estimation of future performance? yeah. Same way that value investors have done it since Graham.

Comment: There are definitely steady indicators of "durable reputation", durable/steady liquidity, lack of "major conflict" (courts, legal actions, scandals. Competitors frequently spread misinformation, use libel tactics), supply/demand gaps, well classified "product feedback" that, if timely scraped from the web, analyzed and identified to be true and feasible, contribute a lot to the assumption of continued growth or decline in stock price.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to predict is already priced in

Comment: if this were actually true 100% of the time an arbitrage would be impossible. This is not true, and the very nature of the stock market makes it so. Companies' valuations in the stock market can and do become inflated or deflated relative to their intrinsic value; it is rare, but does happen.

Comment: You can take some time periods (month, week, 10 days)  and measure factors such as: number of insider purchases per period (typically a reputation boost), number of litigated suits and their outcomes, daily volume (rolling average say for 2-3 days, to know how liquid it is and how high the investor's interest is), macroeconomy and geopolitics, emerging partnerships, competitor events (product released by a competitor may negatively impact stock price), market capitalization.  There's a lot of information that has to be scraped from the web and used together with your financial documents.

Comment: What I mean whatever financial document you have reflecting data, it has a degree of subjectivity, a bias/entropy (corrupt,  inflated or distorted data, or data that does not reflect the real price but rather an outcome of random event, many irregularities and irrationality, entropy).  You can dramatically increase the quality of your predictions by taking into consideration factors that are not just *assumed to be correct* financial records, but all the complementing background events that have impact on price formation.

Comment: Right, I mean we aren't just grabbing financial reports, we are grabbing a lot other other data, indicators, related news etc etc. My question doesn't realy have anything to do with that, its more so about training a network where the data doesnt all have the same amount of datapoints.